# How to write from Vim buffer to console?

Tags: shell, vim

If I run a shell command from inside Vim, say `:!ls`, it's output will still be visible in the shell after I quit Vim.

I want to write selected lines from my current buffer in Vim to the shell in a similar manner. That is, those lines should be visible at the console after I quit Vim. How to do this?

To write lines 4-10 for example, this command did not do that: `:4,10w !tee`

Comment: Why not use `:!cat %`?

Comment: @dlmeetei What if I want to write only some selected lines (say lines 4 to 10) from the buffer? Maybe I want to visually mark those lines and then write those?

Comment: Great, Now you have updated question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

What about simple *cat*ting the file

```
:!cat %
```

(as oposed to `:%!cat` which would print only to buffer)

---

Print only selected lines:

```
:execute '!sed -n ' . line("'<") . ',' . line("'>") . 'p %'
```

You can define a command for that

```
command! -range PrintSelected :execute '!sed -n ' . line("'<") . ',' . line("'>") . 'p %'
```

Comment: This works! What if I want to write only some selected lines (say lines 4 to 10) from the buffer? Maybe I want to visually mark those lines and then write those?

Answer (score 0):

To build upon @pacholik's answer (and answer your extended question from the comments), in order to only list the visual selection (or any other range of lines), you can use `sed`:

```
:execute printf('!sed -n %d,%dp %%', line("'<"), line("'>"))
```